# Web Service and Javascript request on the same localhost port

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, tomcat, localhost

I've got a very simple Axis web service on an Apache Tomcat server (e.g. localhost:9999). I created and run everything with Eclipse Java EE.

I want to invoke that web service on a HTML page with JavaScript (was made in Aptana Studio 3)
- When I open the HTML, there's an error because of the cross-domain-policy.

How can I solve this? Or is it the wrong way?

I tried to run it on the same port as the web service using base-url in the Run Configurations, but it is not working (port is used). Can I get it both running on the same port?

Would be nice if you can help me out.

Comment: just add cors to your 2nd port's response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download Apache Tomcat (doesn't matter the version) you choose the port your server will run on.

If you have Tomcat tied in with Eclipse Java EE, make sure tomcat isn't already running. You can usually check this by right clicking the Tomcat tool icon on your task bar. If it's already running, stop it and then try running tomcat again through eclipse.

If you don't have tomcat tied in with eclipse, here's a tutorial video on how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdThrERsSsI

Hope this helps